# Is there any shortcut to change 1 word per line to any #words per line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, notepad++

For example:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
eleven
twelve
```

to

```
one two three
four five six
seven eight nine
ten eleven twelve
```

I couldn't figure out how to do this and was only able to do vice versa on vscode.

Answer (score 0):

Not a shortcut, but you can easily do such job with find ans replace.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\w+)\R(\w+)\R(\w+)`
- Replace with: `$1 $2 $3`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(\w+)           # group 1, 1 or more word characters
\R              # any kind of linebreak
(\w+)           # group 2, 1 or more word characters
\R
\R              # any kind of linebreak
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not VS Code, but you can do that using this snippet:

> Just bookmark this answer if you need it again (or copy and paste the snippet info into an HTML file on your device). Also, I think the "Copy to clipboard" button doesn't work because the snippet runs in a cross-origin `iframe`, but it should work in a same-origin context.

```js
function splitWordsPerLine (text, wpl = 1) {
  let result = '';
  wpl = wpl < 1 ? 1 : wpl;
  let count = wpl;

  for (const word of text.split(/\s+/)) {
    count -= 1;
    let line = word;
    if (count === 0) {
      line += '\n';
      count = wpl;
    }
    else line += ' ';
    result += line;
  }

  return result.trim();
}

function getWPL (numberInput) {
  if (!numberInput) return 1;
  const wpl = parseInt(numberInput.value, 10);
  return Number.isNaN(wpl) ? 1 : wpl;
}

function handleInput (event) {
  const wpl = getWPL(event.target);
  const textInput = document.getElementById('text');
  if (!textInput) return;
  textInput.value = splitWordsPerLine(textInput.value, wpl);
}

async function handleClick (event) {
  let message = 'Copying failed ';
  const textInput = document.getElementById('text');
  try {
    if (!textInput) throw new Error('No input found');
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(textInput.value);
    message = 'Text copied ✅';
  }
  catch {}
  textInput?.select();
  const setText = str => event.target.textContent = str;
  setText(message);
  setTimeout(() => setText('Copy to clipboard'), 1500);
}

function handlePaste (event) {
  const text = event.clipboardData?.getData('text');
  if (!text) return;

  const wpl = getWPL(document.getElementById('wpl'));
  event.target.value = splitWordsPerLine(text, wpl);

  event.preventDefault();
}

document.getElementById('wpl')?.addEventListener('input', handleInput);
document.getElementById('copy')?.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
document.getElementById('text')?.addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.container.vertical {
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

#copy {
  background-color: black;
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

#wpl, #text {
  border: 1px solid;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

#wpl {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  width: 5rem;
}

#text {
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="container vertical">
  <div class="container">
    <input id="wpl" type="number" min="1" step="1" value="1" />
    <button id="copy">Copy to clipboard</button>
  </div>
  <textarea id="text" rows="0" cols="0" placeholder="Select number of words per line, then paste your text here"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#select-by-line-number) and the command `selectby.lineNr`

- Place the cursor on the first line
- execute command: **Place cursor based on line number, uses boolean expression**
- enter expression: `c+3k` to place a cursor every 3 lines
- maybe expression: `c+3k && n<50` to limit the end line to use
- now use <kbd>End</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Delete</kbd> as often as needed
- press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit Multi Cursor Mode